# Using variables to define Grid.Row in XAML / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

While defining a Form using XAML, I am chaining several blocks of fields.
In order to make XAML code more readable and maintenable in the future, I am trying to define a "base" Row for each block, so relative Rows can be used to define each item of the block instead of absolute ones.

Note the differences for:

```
< ... Grid.Row="" ...>
```

in both cases.

Here is an excerpt of my current code:

```
<!-- Subblock 2 -->
<!-- Address -->
<Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Content="Address:"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Address"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Address (cont.)"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Town"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="ZIP"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="State"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Country"/>
```

And this is what I would like to have:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <!-- Defines starting rows for each block -->
        <System:Int32 x:Key="rowBlock1">0</System:Int32>
        <System:Int32 x:Key="rowBlock2">5</System:Int32>
</Window.Resources>
[...]
<!-- Subblock 2 -->
<!-- Address -->
<Label Grid.Row="{StaticResource rowBlock2} + 0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Content="Address:"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="{StaticResource rowBlock2} + 0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Address"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="{StaticResource rowBlock2} + 1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Address (cont.)"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="{StaticResource rowBlock2} + 2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Town"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="{StaticResource rowBlock2} + 2" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="ZIP"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="{StaticResource rowBlock2} + 3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="State"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="{StaticResource rowBlock2} + 3" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Country"/>
```

Is is possible to achive that with XAML? Any other tip/suggestion on how to avoid absolute Grid.Row values is also welcomed.

Comment: Just create multiple Grids. Each "subblock" has its own Grid and each of those Grids in within a row of a parent Grid.

Comment: Thanks Glen, that's really good idea. But then I have to add the whole <Grid> definition with 12 <ColumnDefinition> elements and an equally large number of <RowDefinition> elements that I use in each block. Is there any way to template or style a Grid so I can avoid so much verbosity in each subblock grid definition?

Comment: You could break this down into separate UserControls to make the XAML a bit simpler. Then just have a master user control to combine them.